HikariCP keep alive query leaking Google Spanner Sessions
I have a spring boot application using HikariCP. The app connects to a google spanner db. I am seeing the following session leak exception caused by HikariCP keep alive queries
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool$PooledSessionFuture.markCheckedOut(SessionPool.java:1338)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool$PooledSessionFuture.access$6200(SessionPool.java:1317)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool.checkoutSession(SessionPool.java:3270)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool.getSession(SessionPool.java:3251)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool.getMultiplexedSessionWithFallback(SessionPool.java:3186)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClientImpl.getMultiplexedSession(DatabaseClientImpl.java:72)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClientImpl.singleUseReadOnlyTransaction(DatabaseClientImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.SingleUseTransaction.executeQueryAsync(SingleUseTransaction.java:237)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.internalExecuteQuery(ConnectionImpl.java:1592)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.internalExecute(ConnectionImpl.java:1022)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.execute(ConnectionImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcStatement.lambda$execute$3(AbstractJdbcStatement.java:290)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcStatement.doWithStatementTimeout(AbstractJdbcStatement.java:230)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcStatement.execute(AbstractJdbcStatement.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeStatement(JdbcStatement.java:257)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:248)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionDead(PoolBase.java:165)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$KeepaliveTask.run(HikariPool.java:854)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

If I set the Leak Detection Threshold my application starts crashing. Incidentally the db queries triggerred from within the business logic are also leaking sessions. I am using FluentJDBC for querying the db. The POM and Code snippets are as below
        var sourceDbHikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

        sourceDbHikariConfig.setDriverClassName(config.getDriverClassName());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(config.getUrl());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setUsername(config.getUsername());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setPassword(config.getPassword());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery(config.getConnectionTestQuery());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(config.getKeepAliveTime());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(config.getMaxPoolSize());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(config.getMinIdleTime());
        sourceDbHikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(config.getConnectionTimeout());

        return new HikariDataSource(sourceDbHikariConfig);

POM
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-project</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codejargon</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluentjdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-spanner-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigtable</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.39.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>


TLDR: Update to at least version 2.16.2 of the Spanner JDBC driver. It is however recommended to always use the latest version of the Spanner JDBC driver. At the time of writing, that is version 2.20.1.
This is unfortunately a known issue when using HikariCP with the Spanner JDBC driver. It was fixed in version 2.16.2 of the JDBC driver. The reason for the leak is that Hikari executes a query, and then never actually reads the data that is returned, and also never closes the ResultSet. Instead, the Statement that was used to execute the keep-alive query is closed, which should have been enough to also release all resources used by the statement. The JDBC driver however failed to clean up the ResultSet that had not been used.
Note however that Spanner JDBC connections do not need these keep-alive queries. Any keep-alive logic that is needed is already executed internally in the JDBC driver. Disabling the HikariCP keep-alive queries, or at least configuring them to be executed as little as possible, is therefore recommended.
